# Pagination: Invalid query parameter

Tags: python, json, pagination, amadeus

I'm testing Amadeus' API following [Amadeus Github tuto](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-python) to get familiar. I didn't know about pagination and it seems difficult to handle.

```
from amadeus import Client, ResponseError
from amadeus import Location
from json_encoder import json


def getFirst():
    response = amadeus.reference_data.locations.get(
        keyword='LON',
        subType=Location.ANY
    )
    return (response)

amadeus = Client(
    client_id=REPLACE_BY_YOUR_API_KEY,
    client_secret=REPLACE_BY_YOUR_API_SECRET
)

try:
    first = getFirst()
    next = amadeus.next(first)
    print(next.data)

except ResponseError as error:
    print(error)
```

**first** call works but with **next** (pagination) Im trying different calls with the same `[400]
[page] Invalid query parameter` error.

This is the [JSON from get in proposal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThaZG.png)

Also I found this [Amadeus pagination calls](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/developer-guides/blob/master/guides/pagination.md) where si used the same kind of calls with success

...Im wondering how can I use properly this function from Amadeus library.

Thanks for reading & help!

Comment: I can reproduce this, bug reported directly on GitHub: https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-python/issues/28 I will update the answer when it's fixed.

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyRoux, Im following the Issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this bug. It has been fixed, you can now install the version 2.0.1 of the Python SDK to get the fix:

> pip install amadeus

**Root cause**:
APIs supporting pagination use a square bracket parameter to index the page and
the offset. The format was not correctly encoded by the `urlencode` method from
`urllib` when building the URL parameter list.

For the following example:

```
{'longitude': 0.1278, 'latitude': 51.5074, 'page': {'offset': 10}}
```

It was encoded as:

```
longitude=0.1278&latitude=51.5074&page={offset : 10}
```

Instead of:

```
longitude=0.1278&latitude=51.5074&page[offset]=10
```

The new private method `_urlencode` parses and prepares the dictionary before the
actual call to `urlencode` is done.